# Unknown Python Syntax

Tags: python, syntax

I've found the following syntax in a python file:

```
 units = (
        (100, 1 << 30, _('%.0f GB')),
        (10, 1 << 30, _('%.1f GB')),
        (1, 1 << 30, _('%.2f GB')),
        (100, 1 << 20, _('%.0f MB')),
        (10, 1 << 20, _('%.1f MB')),
        (1, 1 << 20, _('%.2f MB')),
        (100, 1 << 10, _('%.0f KB')),
        (10, 1 << 10, _('%.1f KB')),
        (1, 1 << 10, _('%.2f KB')),
        (1, 1, _('%.0f bytes')),
        )
```

Does anyone know for what this underscore stands for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: underscore is a valid variable name in python. in this case it's most likely some i18n function

Comment: I'm going to guess it's for i18n/localization.

Comment: Most likely the same as these underscores: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077227/mercurial-python-what-does-the-underscore-function-do

Comment: Ironically enough, it is actual code from the [mercurial.util](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#yqvQ9RM69FY/mercurial/util.py&q=mercurial%20units%20_%20lang:Python&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=1863)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underscore is a valid variable name, so you have to look at the context of your example code. Obviously the underscore is a method which has been defined somewhere else. Usually it's used for translation stuff or similar things.

Comment: thanks; in my humble opinion python & python developers overuse the underscore

Comment: It may get overused, but it's certainly convenient at times.  In a User Interface I'm designing we do something like this to simplify translations:  `from wx import GetTranslation as _`.

Answer (score 3):

As said in other answers, `_` is a valid name for a Python function. It's probable you will find `_()` used as translation function in some I18N packages.

Answer (score 3):

Look further up in the file. With some luck you'll find a statement like this:

```
from Language import _
```

Underscore is often used for i18n.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the `_` is a function. The usual convention is that it used for localisation and internationalisation

Answer (score 0):

The _ function is usually aliased to the GetText get function: http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html