# Assigning a value to single underscore _ in Python/IPython interpreter

Tags: python, function, ipython, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I created this function in Python 2.7 with `ipython`:

```
def _(v):
    return v
```

later if I call `_(somevalue)`, I get `_ = somevalue`.

```
in[3]: _(3)
out[3]: 3
in[4]: print _
out[4]: 3
```

The function has disappeared! If I call `_(4)` I get:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Why? What's wrong with this function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial/Python - What Does The Underscore Function Do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077227/mercurial-python-what-does-the-underscore-function-do)

Comment: @dimo414: No, this is *not* a duplicate of that question. I touch upon that usage of the underscore function in my answer, but that is **not** what the OP is asking about. This is about why the Python interactive interpreter assigned something else to `_`.

Comment: You're right, I realized that after posting the possible duplicate.  Since we cannot [rescind a vote-to-close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) I figured it was more informative to leave the reference (people certainly could land on this page looking for an answer to the linked question, after all) than remove the comment.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The Python interpreter assigns the last expression value to `_`.

This behaviour is limited to the [REPL interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) only, and is intended to assist in interactive coding sessions:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(3.0, 5)
243.0
>>> result = _
>>> result
243.0
```

The *standard* Python interpreter goes to some length to not trample on user-defined values though; if you yourself assign something *else* to `_` then the interpreter will not overwrite that (technically speaking, the [`_` variable is a `__builtin__` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-this-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python), your own assignments are 'regular' globals). You are not using the standard Python interpreter though; you are using IPython, and that interpreter is not that careful.

IPython [documents this behaviour explicitly](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system):

> The following GLOBAL variables always exist (so don’t overwrite them!):
>
> - `[_]` (a single underscore) : stores previous output, like Python’s default interpreter.
>
> *[...]*

In the standard Python REPL environment, if you assigned something to `_` you can still access the last expression result via `__builtins__._` or by deleting the `_` global that shadows it again (`del _`).

Outside of the Python interpreter, `_` is by convention used as the name of the translatable text function (see the [`gettext` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html#internationalizing-your-programs-and-modules); external tools look for that function to extract translatable strings).

And, also by convention, using `_` as an assignment target tells readers of your code that you are going to ignore that value; e.g. `[random.random() for _ in range(5)]` to generate a list of 5 random float values, or `foo, bar, _ = three_values` to signal a 3rd value from a tuple assignment will not be used. When `_` is already used for a `gettext` function, `__` can be used for the same purposes.

Comment: what is an interactive coding session? like a instructional type thing?

Comment: @Stephan: Opening the python interpreter without a script, to try things out at the REPL prompt. The interpreter compiles statements and immediately executes them, making it easy to try something out quickly.

Answer (score 31):

`_` is a special variable in interpreter, it is always assigned to the result of previous expression. So, you shoudn't use it like that.

BTW the problem seems to be related to IPython shell, because your code works fine in normal python shell:

In normal python shell when you assign anything to the variable `_` then it'll remain assigned to that object only, and looses it special behaviour.

---

**Python shell:**

```
>>> 2*2
4
>>> _         #works as expected
4
>>> _ = 2     #after assignment, it's magic functionality is gone
>>> _*5       
10
>>> _
2
```

---

**IPython shell**:

In IPython `_` behaves differently than python shell's `_`; even if you assign it to some variable then also it is going to be updated as soon as you do some calculation.

```
In [1]: 2*2
Out[1]: 4

In [2]: _
Out[2]: 4

In [3]: _ = 10

In [4]: _*10
Out[4]: 100

In [5]: _
Out[5]: 100
```

---

From IPython's [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system):

> The following GLOBAL variables always exist (so don’t overwrite
>   them!):
>
> _ : (a single underscore) : stores previous output, like Python’s
>   default interpreter.
>   ..

From python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> The special identifier `_` is used in the interactive interpreter to
>   store the result of the last evaluation; it is stored in the
>   `__builtin__` module. When not in interactive mode, `_` has no special meaning and is not defined.
>
> **Note**: The name `_` is often used in conjunction with internationalization; refer to the documentation for the gettext
>   module for more information on this convention.

Comment: Although I don't have IPython installed, I can confirm that this is how the normal (the official CPython?) interactive shell acts (in version 2.7.2).

Answer (score -1):

If you create a variable assigned to "_" it gets masked/masks the system variable _.

Comment: What system variable `_` might that be?

Comment: same here, I don't know how to get rid of it