# What does _ in Python do?

Tags: python, syntax

I saw somewhere about the `_` character being used in Python like:

```
print _
```

Can somebody help me explain what it does?

Answer (score 18):

In the interactive interpreter, `_` always refers to the last outputed value:

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> print _
2
>>> 2 + 2
4
>>> print _
4
>>>
```

In normal Python<sup>1</sup> code however, `_` is just a typical name.  You can assign to it as you would any other:

```
_ = 3
print _
# Output: 3
```

Although I wouldn't recommend actually doing this because `_` is a terrible name.  Also,  it is used by convention to mean a name that is simply a placeholder.  An example would be:

```
a, _, b = [1, 2, 3]
```

which uses `_` to mean that we are not interested in the `2`.  Another example is:

```
for _ in range(10):
    function()
```

which means that we are not using the counter variable inside the loop.  Instead, we only want Python to call `function` ten times and need the `_` to have valid syntax.

---

<sup>1</sup>By "Python", I mean CPython, which is the standard flavor of the language.  Other implementations may choose to do things differently.  IPython for example has this to say about underscore-only names:

> The following GLOBAL variables always exist (so don’t overwrite
>   them!):
>
> ```
> [_] (a single underscore) : stores previous output, like Python’s default interpreter.
> [__] (two underscores): next previous.
> [___] (three underscores): next-next previous.
> ```

Source: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.9.1/html/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system

Comment: does this also work in Ipython Notebook?

Comment: @SalilPNavgire It works in IPython shell too, but [slightly differently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17580309/846892).

Answer (score 1):

It's just another variable name, that is typically used for three very different things:

In the Python interactive shell, _ is the value of the last expression that was entered:

```
>>> 3 + 3
6
>>> _ == 6
True
```

It is used to indicate that some variable is just there because it needs to be and won't be used any further:

```
instance, _ = models.MyModel.objects.get_or_create(name="Whee")
```

(here, get_or_create returned a tuple with two elements, only one of which is going
  to be used by us).

The function used for translating strings (often ugettext) is often locally renamed
to _() so that it takes up as little screen space as possible:

```
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

 print(_("This is a translatable string."))
```

Answer (score 0):

`'_'`is a legal python character just like most other Programming Languages. I think MATLAB is the exception where you cannot use that for any MATLAB file names. I know because I tried it in the past and it failed. Don't know if this has been changed since R2014b. In python, the best examples are `__init__`, `__self__`, `__str__`, `__repr__`, etc.

Rather than asking questions and having confusions in your mind, just type it and see what happens. You won't break anything :D. Open Python IDLE, and press CTRL+. you will see lots of Python native variables and functions named with `_` or even `__`. I quite liked the variable assignment example provided by @iCodez here :)