# python underscore function name

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

I was reading the django article on form validatin [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror) and i came across this

```
ValidationError(_('Invalid value'), code='invalid')
```

my question is what does the `_('Invalid value')` does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial/Python - What Does The Underscore Function Do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077227/mercurial-python-what-does-the-underscore-function-do)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's for translation purpose

you should see this at the begining of the script

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

[you can see a complete explanation in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/)

Answer (score 2):

`_` is often associated with internationalization

might be duplication of [Mercurial/Python - What Does The Underscore Function Do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077227/mercurial-python-what-does-the-underscore-function-do)